# SQL query expanding one column based on the values in another column

Tags: sql

I have a table that has a column for questions and a column for responses along with a number of other fields.  Each row has version number associated with it so you know what the latest groups of question and responses are.   So the table looks something like :

```
from_cntry     to_cntry     Version   question           answer     
Peru           Egypt          39      Max Comp          unlimited
Peru           Egypt          38      Maxx Comp         unlimited 
Peru           Egypt          39      Actual Comp       Determined by country agreement 
Brazil         Cameroon       39      Actual Comp       Determined by country agreement 
Brazil         Cameroon       39      Max Comp          300000
Brazil         Cameroon       38      Max Comp          Unlimited
```

For the latest version of responses, I want to display the responses in columns titled with the corresponding question as follows:

```
From_cntry      To_cntry        Max Comp      Actual Comp
 Peru            Egypt           unlimited    Determined by country agreement  
Brazil          Cameroon          300000       Determined by country agreement
```

(I could not figure out how to display columns here so I included comma's where a new column would be)

I am able to get the questions and responses to display the way I want them but when I try to include the other fields I get an error.  The following works for expanding the question and response info.

```
SELECT    
     MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Max Comp' THEN response else null END)  as Max Comp
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Actual Comp' THEN Response else null end) as Actual Comp
from table
```

I added the other fields to the select statement as follows:

```
SELECT from_cntry, to_cntry,    
     MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Max Comp' THEN response else null END)  as Max Comp
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Actual Comp' THEN Response else null end) as Actual Comp
from table
```

I get the following error:  not a single-group group function.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use aggregation functions (such as SUM,COUNT,MAX,MIN..) you have to group by all other columns you have in your select. So your select should look like:

```
SELECT from_cntry, to_cntry,    
     MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Max Comp' THEN response else null END)  as Max Comp
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Actual Comp' THEN Response else null end) as Actual Comp
from table 

Group by from_cntry, to_cntry
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `group by`. When using aggregation all columns being selected should be in your group by.

```
SELECT from_cntry, to_cntry,    
     MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Max Comp' THEN response else null END)  as Max Comp
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Actual Comp' THEN Response else null end) as Actual Comp
from table
group by from_cntry, to_cntry
```